# django реализация view

Tags: python, django

Модель:

```
class LikeDislike(models.Model):
    like = models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name='like')
    dis_like =  models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='dis_like')

    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey()

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'{self.content_object.title},{self.content_object}'
    class  Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Лайки'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Лайки'
```

view:

```
class LikeView(View):
    model = None
    vote = None
    def post(self, request, pk):
        vt = self.vote
        obj = self.model.objects.get(pk=pk)
        if  list(obj.vote.all()) == []:
            like_obj = LikeDislike.objects.create(content_object=obj)
        else:
            like_obj = LikeDislike.objects.get(object_id=obj.id)
        if request.user in like.like.all():
            like_obj.like.remove(request.user)
        elif request.user in like.dis_like.all():
            like_obj.dis_like.remove(request.user)
        else:
            like_obj.like.add(request.user)
       
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('detail_post', args=[str(pk)]))
```

urlpatterns:

```
path('like/<int:pk>/', views.LikeView.as_view(model=Post, vote=LikeDislike.like), name='like')
```

Не могу сообразить, как написать код что-бы, в`like_obj.like.remove(request.user)` подставить переменную `vt` вместо `like`.При выполнение выше поставленной задачи, django ругается, что в классе `Likedislike`, нету аргумента `vt`. Суть данной задачи заключается в том, что-бы не писать новую вьюшку, а ограничится одной, изменяя на нужный аргумент класса в urlpatterns.

Comment: Так создайте в классе Likedislike поле vt и используйте его.

Comment: у вас строчка кода, которая пытается вытянуть объект obj = self.model.objects.get(pk=pk). Но вы задали аттрибут класса model = None. Перед первым if выведите свой объект, и если он None , тогда ошибка там.

Comment: Так же , если я не ошибаюсь, в django нету возможности, удалить конкретное поле и вставить новое. Там идёт метод save, который либо обновляет модель либо создаёт. По этому, вам нужно получить объект , который вы хотите изменить и потом переопределить его поле например   like_obj.dis_like = request._user и потом у данного объекта вызвать метод save.   like_obj.save()

Comment: @WilteRatenau  в```urlpatterns``` переменная  model принимает значение нужной модели, в примере это модель ```Post```.